# Calculating Last Year Total

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau 8.2,How do I get the Last Year Total ?

i,e on applying filter Year=2013 then Total should represent the sales for 2012(Total)

I have Month/Year On the Columns.

The case is explained in [`.twbx file.](http://www.filedropper.com/lastyearsales_1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of ways to accomplish that, and all of them depend on how you want to display data. I'll go with the view that you have a first column with the previous year figure, and a monthly series of current year (as I guess it is what you're trying to achieve).

The simplest way to achieve that is not doing it all in the same worksheet. Rather, do the monthly calculations in one sheet, and the last year calculation in another sheet, them put them side by side on a dashboard.

The monthly figures you already have (just drop the Last Year field). The Last year can be easily achieved by simply plotting SUM(Sales) on screen.

The trick is on how performing the filter. I would create a parameter (let's call it Year) and 2 fields to be used as filter. Current year filter: YEAR([Order Date]) = Year, and previous year filter: YEAR([Order Date]) = Year - 1

Than drag those filters to the proper worksheet (keep True values). Now you have a parameter that controls the filter on both sheets

Comment: Thanks man! but boss said its `pathetic`, I saw you answer just now after I implemented the same way ! but thanks +1:)

Comment: any other way using the parameters concept?

Comment: What exactly is pathetic? What is he concerned about? What exactly he didn't like? There are multiple ways to solve a problem, but I need to know what is the problem before I try to solve it

Comment: The standard report(done in jaspersoft) contains,the column `Last year Total` in the same sheet, so as I done the same job using 2 sheets that's where it went wrong,I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Well, if you desperately needs it to be on the same sheet, one alternative is to create 12 fields, one for each month, with basically IF MONTH([Order Date]) = XX AND Year([Order Date]) = Year THEN [Sales] END. Then you select all those 12 fields plus the Last Year field (IF YEAR([Order Date]) = Year - 1 THEN [Sales] END), and select side-by-side bars view. It's brute force, but it works